# Error 2 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Hilversum.Geluidsfragment>' to 'Hilversum.Geluidsfragment

Tags: c#, string

Heyy,
I get this error:

> Error  2   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'Hilversum.Geluidsfragment

At this line:

```
Geluidsfragment fragment = bgExperience.GetFragmenten(item)
```

In this code:

```
private void info_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    int index = this.info.IndexFromPoint(e.Location);
    string item = info.Items[index].ToString();
    tbFragmentNr.Text = item;
    Geluidsfragment fragment = bgExperience.GetFragmenten(item);
     try
     {
         lbAfspeelInfo.Text = fragment.AlsString();

         fragment.Play();
     }
     catch (NullReferenceException ex)
     {
         MessageBox.Show("Nummer bestaat niet");
     }
}
```

This is the `GetFragmenten` method:

```
public List<Geluidsfragment> GetFragmenten(String p)
{
    List<Geluidsfragment> resultaten = new List<Geluidsfragment>();

    foreach (Geluidsfragment fragment in fragmenten)
        if (fragment.Titel.IndexOf(p) != -1)
            resultaten.Add(fragment);

    return resultaten;
}
```

This is AlsString Methode:

```
public String AlsString()
{
    return "Nr " + nr + ": " + titel + " - " + TijdsduurString;
}
```

Please help me :(

Comment: It looks to me like the method is returning a List<Geluidsfragment> and the variable is just a single instance of the object.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling a function that returns a

```
public List<Geluidsfragment> GetFragmenten(String p)
{
    //...
}
```

But you're assigning it to a variable that doesn't hold a List and instead holds a single instance:

```
Geluidsfragment fragment = bgExperience.GetFragmenten(item);
```

should be:

```
List<Geluidsfragment> fragmenten = bgExperience.GetFragmenten(item);
```

EDIT: From there you'd do something like:

```
foreach (Geluidsfragment fragment in fragmenten) 
{
    fragment.Play();
}
```

I think there's a more fundamental problem though. It looks like you're wanting to play an audio clip when something is double-clicked...but your `GetFragmenten` function returns multiple clips. Is this really what you want?

Comment: Oh yeah true, but now i have 2 new errors:

Comment: Error 3 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Hilversum.Geluidsfragment>' does not contain a definition for 'Play' and no extension method 'Play' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Hilversum.Geluidsfragment>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @user3109152: have you tried to read the error message? Or do you expect you will write some messy code and we will fix it for you?

Comment: Well yeah, changing the type of that variable means you have to treat it differently. If you read the error you'll find that it's because you now have a List of Geluidsfragment as opposed to a single instance.

Comment: Uh yes i did, but i DO hava a methode for 'Play'

Comment: but `Play` is on `Geluidsfragment`, not on `List<T>`

Comment: But you can't ask the list to Play you have to ask an item in the list to play

Comment: IT should be like fragment[item].Play(); (or something) like that right..?

Comment: Your object `item` is just a string.  You have to figure out which element in the list is the one you want to play and use the index of that element.  If this is a media player program, you probably want to send that list to the playlist and start playing the first one, which would be `fragment[0].Play()`

Comment: He is right, i just want to play that ONLY file, and not multiply files. So i have to search in my List to play that file, but im not so good in C# i trying to learn ...

Comment: I Fixed it with ur help guys, THankyou